# How to store array to Vuex in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Can someone tell me how to write an array of objects in Vuex
I will explain the essence
In this situation, I need to create an order management system
I have an array of products with different data
This array I get from the server using axios request
Via v-for, I displayed this array in the select option html tag
Next, by clicking on the html option  tag, I need to add the product to the data table
Also, with the addition of a specific product to the table, it is necessary that the product for which a click is made is recorded in the Vuex store, but not with rewriting, but with addition to existing data
Next, in synchronization with the addition to the Vuex store, information is output from the Vuex store to the table

this is my code in Vue Component

```
<div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Price</th>
                                            <th>QTY</th>
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="products">Select Products</label>
                                            <select v-model="orderData" @change="addOrderData" id="products"  class="form-control">
                                                <option  v-for="product in products" multiple v-bind:value="{productId: product.id, name: product.name, price: product.price}">{{product.name}}</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <pre>{{orderData}}</pre>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>

data() {
        return {
            selected: '',
            formData: {
                userId: ''
            },
            orderData: {
                productId: [],
                price: [],
                total: [],
                quantity: []
            }
        }
    },

methods: {
        addOrderData()
        {
            let data = {
                productId: this.orderData.productId,
                name: this.orderData.name,
                price: this.orderData.price,
            }
            this.$store.commit('orders/setOrderProduct', data)
        }
    },
```

this is my code in Vuex store

```
function initialState () {
const orderProducts = [];
return {
    orderProducts
}}

const getters = {
orderProducts(state)
{
    return state.orderProduct;
},};

const mutations = {
setOrderProduct(state, orderProduct)
{
    state.orderProduct = orderProduct;
}};
```

Comment: have you actually tried pushing to `orderProducts`, all you're doing is assigning to `orderProduct`, which is never initialized. Your `orderProducts` getter is also only returning a single `orderProduct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, please check the following:

template:

```
  <select v-model="orderData" @change="addOrderData">
    <option v-for="(product) in products" :key="product.productId" :value="{productId: product.productId, name: product.name, price: product.price}">
      {{product.productId}} - {{product.name}}</option>
  </select>

  <br /><br />

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody v-if="orderProducts.length > 0">
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in orderProducts" :key="index">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.price}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody v-else>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">No products to display</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

code:

```
Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    orderProducts: []
  },
  mutations: {
    addProduct(state, payload) {
      state.orderProducts.push(payload);
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      products: [{
          productId: 1,
          name: 'Product One',
          price: 10
        },
        {
          productId: 2,
          name: 'Product Two',
          price: 15
        }
      ],
      orderData: {
        productId: [],
        price: [],
        total: [],
        quantity: []
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    orderProducts() {
      return this.$store.state.orderProducts;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addOrderData() {
      this.$store.commit('addProduct', this.orderData);
    }
  }
});
```

The idea is when `change` event is triggered by selecting an option, you `commit` mutation to the `store` with the selected product as `payload`. The `orderProducts` computed property will refresh, and the table will get the latest data. You can check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zdjn4uov/2/).